# largest distance between vertices on a polyhedron

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I have a polyhedron defined by m inequations and n unknowns. 
I am interested in the largest distance between two vertices (the number of edges I have to follow from one vertex to another).
I am interested in references, links etc...
thanks 
Patrick Teller

Comment: This is a difficult problem and related to the Hirsch conjecture, see here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirsch_conjecture

Comment: Thanks as it is far from my fields your indication is really useful for me